# How to capitalize each word in JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to capitalize each first letter in a simple JS array, 
the code works fine in the console log - but not on the output

Thanks.

```
<select id="selectId">
<option value="hello">one</option>
<option value="hello">two</option>
<option value="hello">three</option>
```

```
var arr=[];
$("#selectId >option").each(function() {

   arr.push(this.text.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + this.text.substr(1));

});
var i, len, text;
for (i = 0, len = arr.length, text = ""; i < len; i++) {

    console.log(arr[i]);
    $("#select").text(arr[i]);
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/ujuvus21/#&togetherjs=qfUM271V6a)

Comment: there is no element with id `select`

Comment: ... And you are trying to edit text of the select element, not the options.

Comment: Do not `.push()` inside `each()`. `map()` is designed exactly for these purposes.

Comment: caching of Array.length is redundant nowadays. Array does it internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr=[];
$("#selectId >option").each(function() {

   arr.push(this.text.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + this.text.substr(1));

});
var i, len, text;
for (i = 0, len = arr.length, text = ""; i < len; i++) {

    console.log(arr[i]);
    $("#select").text(arr[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectId" style="text-transform: capitalize;">
<option value="hello">one</option>
<option value="hello">two</option>
<option value="hello">three</option>
```

Comment: Why not `.map` instead of `.each`?

Comment: Yes we can do using map also.

Answer (score 1):

Add one class in css

```css
.capitalize{text-transform: capitalize;}
```

and in HTML add whereever you want to capitalize.

Comment: Indeed, it is a good alternative to notice (and the one to use in this example) but it does not answer to the question, that might be a simplified case :)

Comment: Well, that's the cleanest answer. I don't know if the OP wanted a specific javascript or jquery answer, but maybe he doesn't even know about this css property. +1

Comment: Note that this is a display only solution - if the OP is wanted  capitalised content that is to be stored or otherwise manipulated the actual content is still lower case - it just renders in this instance as capitalised.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="selectId">
<option value="hello">one</option>
<option value="hello">two</option>
<option value="hello">three</option>
```

first select all dropdown value in a array

```
var selected = $('select[name="selectId"]').map(function(){
    if ($(this).val())
        return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

now use String.toUpperCase()

```
var upperCasedArray = $.map(selected , function(item, index) {
    return item.toUpperCase();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use substring instead of substr. Substring is understood in more browsers .
Another solution :

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit each option text, not the "text of the select" which does not mean anything in fact.

```
$("#selectId > option").each(function() {
   $(this).text(
       this.text.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + this.text.substr(1)
   );
});
```

I removed your intermediate array for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

honestly you dont need a lib like jquery for this:

```js
var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelector("#selectId").options, function (option) {
    var text = option.textContent;
    return option.textContent = text.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + text.substr(1);
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<select id="selectId">
    <option value="hello">one</option>
    <option value="hello">two</option>
    <option value="hello">three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres's how you capitalize every word

```
function capitalize(string) {
   return typeof string === 'string' 
       ? string.toLowerCase().replace(/(^\w|\s\w)/g, m => m.toUpperCase()) 
       : string
}
```